# Implementing the Bartels–Stewart algorithm in Eigen3?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigen3

In the past when I've needed to solve the Sylvester equation, `AX + XB = C`, I've used `scipy`'s function, `solve_sylvester` [1], which apparently works by using the Bartels-Stewart algorithm to get things into upper triangular form, and then solving the equation using `lapack`.

I now need to solve the equation using `eigen`.  `eigen` provides an function, `matrix_function_solve_triangular_sylvester` [2], which seems by the documentation to be similar to the `lapack` function which `scipy` calls.  I'm attempting to translate exactly `scipy`'s implementation in `eigen3`, but in the end my value for `X` doesn't satisfy the equation.  Here's my implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions>

int main()
{

  Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3> A;
  A << -17,  -6,  0,
       -15,   6,  14,
         9, -12,  19;

  Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 5> B;
  B << 5, -17, -12,  16,  11,
      -4,  19,  -1,   9,  13,
       1,   3,   5,  -5,   2,
       8, -15,   5,  14, -12,
      -2,  -4,  13,  -8, -17;

  Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 5> Q;
  Q <<   6,   5, -17,  12,   4,
       -11,  15,   8,   1,   7,
        15,  -3,   9, -19, -10;

  Eigen::RealSchur<Eigen::MatrixXd> SchurA(A);
  Eigen::MatrixXd R = SchurA.matrixT();
  Eigen::MatrixXd U = SchurA.matrixU();

  Eigen::RealSchur<Eigen::MatrixXd> SchurB(B.transpose());
  Eigen::MatrixXd S = SchurB.matrixT();
  Eigen::MatrixXd V = SchurB.matrixU();

  Eigen::MatrixXd F = (U.transpose() * Q) * V;

  Eigen::MatrixXd Y =
    Eigen::internal::matrix_function_solve_triangular_sylvester(R, S, F);

  Eigen::MatrixXd X = (U * Y) * V.transpose();

  Eigen::MatrixXd Q_calc = A * X + X * B;

  std::cout << Q_calc - Q << std::endl;
  // Should be all zeros, but instead getting:
  // 421.868  193.032 -208.273  42.7449 -3.57527
  //-1651.66 -390.314  2043.59  -1611.1 -1843.91
  //-67.4093  207.414  1168.89 -1240.54 -1650.48

  return EXIT_SUCCESS; 

}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[1] https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/linalg/_solvers.py#L23

[2] https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/dbb0b1f3b07a261d01f43f8fb94e85ceede9fac7/unsupported/Eigen/src/MatrixFunctions/MatrixFunction.h?at=default#lines-274

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chtz is correct; this is due to the Schurr decomposition matrix being quasi-triangular rather than triangular. The eigen solver you are using cannot deal with such matrices. However, chtz is wrong in that there are Sylvester solvers that can deal with quasi-triangular solvers. For example lapack's [trsyl](https://www.smcm.iqfr.csic.es/docs/intel/mkl/mkl_manual/lse/functn_trsyl.htm) can deal with quasi-triangular matrices. This is what is called by `scipy`, which explains why the OP's scipy implementation worked fine.

Comment: I did not claim whether there is or isn't a Sylvester-solver which can handle quasi triangular matrices ...

Answer (score 3):

Your `A` and `B` matrices have non-real eigenvalues, therefore their `RealSchur` decomposition will be non-triangular (only "quasi-triangular", i.e., it contains a 2x2 block on the diagonal). If you compile without `-DNDEBUG`, you should get an assertion like this:

```
../eigen/unsupported/Eigen/src/MatrixFunctions/MatrixFunction.h:277: MatrixType Eigen::internal::matrix_function_solve_triangular_sylvester(const MatrixType&, const MatrixType&, const MatrixType&) [with MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>]: Assertion `A.isUpperTriangular()' failed.
```

I don't know, if there is a Sylvester-solver which also handles quasi-triangular matrices, but the easiest solution using Eigen methods would be to use the `ComplexSchur` decomposition (also use `adjoint()` instead of `transpose()` -- and don't transpose `B`):

```
Eigen::ComplexSchur<Eigen::MatrixXd> SchurA(A);
Eigen::MatrixXcd R = SchurA.matrixT();
Eigen::MatrixXcd U = SchurA.matrixU();

Eigen::ComplexSchur<Eigen::MatrixXd> SchurB(B);
Eigen::MatrixXcd S = SchurB.matrixT();
Eigen::MatrixXcd V = SchurB.matrixU();

Eigen::MatrixXcd F = (U.adjoint() * Q) * V;

Eigen::MatrixXcd Y =
  Eigen::internal::matrix_function_solve_triangular_sylvester(R, S, F);

Eigen::MatrixXcd X = (U * Y) * V.adjoint();

Eigen::MatrixXcd Q_calc = A * X + X * B;
```

I think `X` should always be real, so you can replace the last two lines by

```
Eigen::MatrixXd X = ((U * Y) * V.adjoint()).real();

Eigen::MatrixXd Q_calc = A * X + X * B;
```

Comment: Any thoughts on a version using only real numbers? I posted a followup to this question / solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62021064/implementing-the-bartels-stewart-algorithm-in-eigen3-real-matrices-only