# Solving Sylvester equations in PyTorch

Tags: python, scipy, pytorch, linear-algebra, backpropagation

I'm trying to solve a Sylvester matrix equation of the form

> AX + XB = C

From what I've seen, these equations are usually solved with the Bartels-Stewart algorithm taking successive Schur decompositions. I'm aware `scipy.linalg` already has a `solve_sylvester` function, but I'm integrating the solution to the Sylvester equation into a neural network, so I need a way to calculate gradients to make A, B, and C learnable. Currently, I'm just solving a linear system with `torch.linalg.solve` using the Kronecker product and vectorization trick, but this has terrible runtime complexity. I haven't found any PyTorch support for Sylvester equations, let alone Schur decompositions, but before I try to implement Barters-Stewart on the GPU, is there a simpler way to find the gradients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially I wrote a solution that would give complex `X` based on [Bartels-Stewart algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartels%E2%80%93Stewart_algorithm) for the `m=n` case. I had some problems because the eigenvector matrix is not accurate enough. Also the real part gives the real solution, and the imaginary part must be a solution for `AX - XB = 0`

```py
import torch

def sylvester(A, B, C, X=None):
    m = B.shape[-1];
    n = A.shape[-1];
    R, U = torch.linalg.eig(A)
    S, V = torch.linalg.eig(B)
    F = torch.linalg.solve(U, (C + 0j) @ V)
    W = R[..., :, None] - S[..., None, :]
    Y = F / W
    X = U[...,:n,:n] @ Y[...,:n,:m] @ torch.linalg.inv(V)[...,:m,:m]
    return X.real if all(torch.isreal(x.flatten()[0]) 
                for x in [A, B, C]) else X
```

As can be verified on the GPU with

```py
device='cuda'
# Try different dimensions
for batch_size, M, N in [(1, 4, 4), (20, 16, 16), (6, 13, 17), (11, 29, 23)]:
    print(batch_size, (M, N))
    A = torch.randn((batch_size, N, N), dtype=torch.float64, 
                    device=device, requires_grad=True)
    B = torch.randn((batch_size, M, M), dtype=torch.float64, 
                    device=device, requires_grad=True)
    X = torch.randn((batch_size, N, M), dtype=torch.float64, 
                    device=device, requires_grad=True)
    C = A @ X - X @ B
    X_ = sylvester(A, B, C)
    C_ = (A) @ X_ - X_ @ (B)
    print(torch.max(abs(C - C_)))
    X.sum().backward()
```

A faster algorithm, but inaccurate in the current pytorch version is

```
def sylvester_of_the_future(A, B, C):
    def h(V):
        return V.transpose(-1,-2).conj()
    m = B.shape[-1];
    n = A.shape[-1];
    R, U = torch.linalg.eig(A)
    S, V = torch.linalg.eig(B)
    F = h(U) @ (C + 0j) @ V
    W = R[..., :, None] - S[..., None, :]
    Y = F / W
    X = U[...,:n,:n] @ Y[...,:n,:m] @ h(V)[...,:m,:m]
    return X.real if all(torch.isreal(x.flatten()[0]) for x in [A, B, C]) else X
```

I will leave it here maybe in the future it will work properly.

Comment: This looks great, although it looks like it depends on C being square. Is there a way to do this where C is m x n?

Comment: I think it also depends on A and B being the same size. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @ApodicticAppleJuice I changed the answer to address the generic case, and also to give a real solution for real input matrices.

Comment: Sorry, just saw this. I tried running, and after fixing what I think was a mis-type (torch.isreal(a.flatten()[0]) should be using x not a, I think) and casting X_ to a torch.complex128, the allclose assertion is failing.

Comment: Sorry, when I pasted the code here I decided to make `W = R - S ; Y = F / W` inline, and I did `Y = F / R - S` instead of `Y = F / (R -S)`, some other fomatting led to missing colons. Now I tried to keep the code the closest I could form the original.

Comment: One more thing, if you have fixed A and/or B this method can be accelerated a lot, or if you can relate A and B, e.g the usual case `B=A.T` this can be made about 2x faster.

Comment: Thanks for your work! It seems like you are solving `AX - XB = C` though, which differs by a sign from what OP asked for, no?
For solving `AX + XB = C` we would need to have a `+` when defining `W`.

Comment: You are right, thank you. When I have time I will change that. Either way the two problems are equivalent. You can just pass -B to the function and you solve the original problem.